# Como retornar variáveis em todas as views no laravel?

Tags: laravel

Tenho um projecto laravel, tenho o index.blade.php que em que a parte do header e footer sao fixas, e content e que muda.
O meu problema e retornar dados de um controller para o footer, ele lista-me os dados quando estou na homepage quando mudo de url da-me um erro de undefined variable que sao as variaveis que tenho no footer.

**Rota**

```
Route::get('/', 'ListaDadosHomeController@lista_dados_home');
```

**Controller**

```
public function lista_dados_home (){

    $builder = DB::table('categorias')
            ->select('*')
            ->where('activo', '=', '1');

    $categorias_home = $builder->get();

    // LISTA FOODIES HOME

    $opinioes = DB::raw('(SELECT COUNT(*) AS id FROM posts WHERE user_id = users_social.id) as count_opinioes');

    $seguidores = DB::raw('(SELECT COUNT(*) AS followed FROM seguidores WHERE followed = users_social.id) as `count_seguidores`');

    $builder = DB::table('users_social')
            ->select('*', $opinioes, $seguidores)
            ->where('activo', '=', '1');

    $top_foodies = $builder->limit(12)->get();

    // CONTA NUMERO DE ESTABELECIMENTOS

    $restaurantes = DB::table('estabelecimentos')->where('categoria', '=', 'restauracao')->count();
    $cafes = DB::table('estabelecimentos')->where('categoria', '=', 'bares')->count();
    $hoteis = DB::table('estabelecimentos')->where('categoria', '=', 'hotelaria')->count();
    $opinioes = DB::table('posts')->count();

    return view('home', ['top_foodies' => $top_foodies], ['categorias_home' => $categorias_home])->with('restaurantes', $restaurantes)->with('cafes', $cafes)->with('hoteis', $hoteis)->with('opinioes', $opinioes);

    return view('index')->with('restaurantes', $restaurantes)->with('cafes', $cafes)->with('hoteis', $hoteis)->with('opinioes', $opinioes);

}
```

Comment: Não tem nenhum código aí pra poder explicar ou postar? A pergunta da forma colocada fica difícil de responder.

Comment: Já coloquei esqueci

Comment: Adicione o código da view index para podermos auxiliar

Comment: Cara tá muito confuso isso ai, por favor tenta explicar melhor.